# Tripledes from hardware

Tags: c#, cryptography

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace SmartCardSign
{
    class SCSign
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // To idendify the Smart Card CryptoGraphic Providers on your
            // computer, use the Microsoft Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).
            // The available Smart Card CryptoGraphic Providers are listed
            // in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider.


            // Create a new CspParameters object that identifies a 
            // Smart Card CryptoGraphic Provider.
            // The 1st parameter comes from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider Types.
            // The 2nd parameter comes from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider.
            CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Schlumberger Cryptographic Service Provider");
            csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;

            // Initialize an RSACryptoServiceProvider object using
            // the CspParameters object.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);

            // Create some data to sign.
            byte[] data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

            Console.WriteLine("Data         : " + BitConverter.ToString(data));

            // Sign the data using the Smart Card CryptoGraphic Provider.
            byte[] sig = rsa.SignData(data, "SHA1");

            Console.WriteLine("Signature    : " + BitConverter.ToString(sig));

            // Verify the data using the Smart Card CryptoGraphic Provider.
            bool verified = rsa.VerifyData(data, "SHA1", sig);

            Console.WriteLine("Verified     : " + verified);

        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement same with tripledes? I tried but cant find a solution.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-access-hardware-encryption-devices

Comment: Found smth like this but unfortunately not a solution :( http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LWy3Sf0KhywJ:www.hivmr.com/db/c9dp7az3kssksz1pczp3xjp3kxm883cs+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=tr  TripleDES tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

// Encrypt 3DES with RSA
byte[] encryptedSessionKey = rsa_dnet.Encrypt(tripleDES.Key, false);

Comment: Any specific use case for this? Why not use hybrid cryptography?

Comment: I need triple des encryption with Hardware Encryption Devices like eToken Base Cryptographic Provider.Is iı possible with pkcs library?

Comment: Yes, but PKCS#11 (the 11 part is required here) is a relatively low level standard. Quite often with smart cards you get a partial PKCS#11 library, possibly augmented with a software library to perform the encryption with symmetric ciphers. Using 3DES on a HW device is **not** a use case. It is a *solution for a specific use case*. You don't have to tell, but this may be an XY problem (look it up!).

Comment: Thank you for help @Maarten Bodewes. One last question the answer I post is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you cannot. And the reason is relatively simple: symmetric ciphers, such as triple-DES are not very useful for person to person cryptography such as signature generation (or MAC for symmetric algorithms) or encryption.

The advantage of asymmetric ciphers is that you can distribute the encryption key to other persons. To do this the other person needs to be certain that they receive the correct key: the key needs to be *trusted*. For this a Public Key Infrastructure or PKI needs to be setup. Known PKI's are PGP and PKIX which is based on X.509 certificates - the same that are used for your HTTPS connections.

So triple DES on a smart card only makes sense if other entities can use the same key. This would be just to gain a tiny performance enhancement because you can encrypt with a public key as well, even in software. Then you can decrypt using the private key on the card. Generally a hybrid cryptosystem is used where a symmetric key such as a triple-DES key is established using RSA, after which the message is encrypted with that key.

That's not to say it is impossible - I've actually designed a PKCS#11 compliant smart card, but most PKCS#11 and CSP's implementations won't support 3DES, and then you would need to have a compatible smart card with a 3DES key as well. Also see the [answer from BartonJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53637636/589259).

Answer (score 1):

```
using (Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11("cryptoki.dll", true))
            {
                // Get list of available slots with token present
                List<Slot> slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(true);

                // Find first slot with token present
                Slot slot = slots[0];

                // Open RO session
                using (Session session = slot.OpenSession(true))
                {
                    session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, "userPin");

                    // Prepare attribute template that defines search criteria
                    List<ObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
                    objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, "TestKey"));

                    // Initialize searching
                    session.FindObjectsInit(objectAttributes);

                    // Get search results
                    List<ObjectHandle> foundObjects = session.FindObjects(2);

                    // Terminate searching
                    session.FindObjectsFinal();

                    ObjectHandle objectHandle = foundObjects[0];

                    byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("00000000");
                    byte[] inputData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data to encrypt.");

                    Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_DES3_CBC, iv);

                    byte[] result = session.Encrypt(mechanism, objectHandle, inputData);

                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(result)); 
                }
            }
```

İs that possbile solution?

Comment: Sure, if it works it works. But many CSP's / PKCS#11 compatible devices that work for smart cards won't expose that kind of functionality.

Comment: Some do, I've designed such a solution myself. You could create it based on e.g. [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC), which also offers has a CSP wrapper. But as you may guess, it is RSA only at this time. This in case you really really need it :)

Answer (score 1):

If have a TripleDES key on a hardware device and know the CNG KSP and key name, you should be able to use TripleDESCng:

```
using (TripleDES des3 = new TripleDESCng("YourKeyIdentifier", new CngProvider("Your KSP Name"))
{
   // So long as you use CreateEncryptor() or CreateDecryptor() (the 0-argument ones)
   // the operation is done on the hardware.
}
```

This, of course, requires that you have a hardware device that supports DES3-EDE.

Getting such a key onto the device is an exercise left to the reader.